# Is it possible to iterate a dictionary inside ForEach in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, foreach, swiftui

I am trying to iterate a  @Published dictionary from a viewModel in a view in SwiftUI. I get an error saying that:

> Initializer 'init(_:id:content:)' requires that 'Dictionary<InterestDomain, Bool>.Keys' conform to 'RandomAccessCollection'

How can I iterate a dictionary inside a ForEach? this is my code:

```
ForEach(viewModel.userDomains.keys.indices, id: \.self) { index in
    VStack {
        DomainOfInterestElement(isActive: self.$isActive, domain: self.viewModel.userDomains.keys[index].name)
        if index != self.viewModel.domains.count - 1 {
            Divider().padding(.bottom, 12)
        }
    }
}.padding([.trailing, .leading], 12)
```

Comment: Maybe your view model should expose an array instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because a Dictionary is *unordered*. So its keys are *unordered* as well.

You need to make it ordered using `Array`:

```
ForEach(Array(viewModel.userDomains.keys).indices, id: \.self) { ...
```

---

As they are ordered randomly, you may also want to sort them:

```
ForEach(Array(viewModel.userDomains.keys).sorted().indices, id: \.self) { ...
```

But as the ordering and sorting gets more complex, you may think of moving  the logic to the `ViewModel` instead.